# Use a fork of Restkit on github via CocoaPods?

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit, cocoapods

restkit is using in a different way the oauth2 protocol, I need to change the code to be able to use it in my way:

From:

```
// OAuth 2 valid request
if (self.authenticationType == RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth2) {
    NSString *authorizationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth2 %@", self.OAuth2AccessToken];
    [_URLRequest setValue:authorizationString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
}
```

to:

```
// OAuth 2 valid request
if (self.authenticationType == RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth2) {
    NSString *authorizationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", self.OAuth2AccessToken];
    [_URLRequest setValue:authorizationString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
}
```

Use of "Bearer" instead of "Oauth2" ....

I'm using CocoaPods to import restkit in my project.

Can I fork Restkit repository on github and use the fork via CocoaPod instead of the official version?

Comment: If you think your changes make sense try to make a pull request to the original project. As a bonus you won't have to worry about maintaining your fork in the future.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You certainly can. Take a look at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Dependency-declaration-options

If RestKit included its `.podspec` file in the repository then you could just change your `Podfile` to point to your fork i.e.

```
pod 'RestKit', :git => 'https://github.com/you/RestKit.git'
```

Unfortunately RestKit does not include its `.podspec`. Instead copy `RestKit.podspec` from https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/RestKit/0.10.2/RestKit.podspec and add it to your project. Edit the `.podspec` to use your fork as its source. You can then specify a local `.podspec` in your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'RestKit', :podspec => 'local/path/to/RestKit.podspec'
```

Alternately you might just add this `.podspec` to your fork and use the former dependency declaration.

Comment: Thanks I was about to answer a t my own question !

Comment: You can also point a precise `, :commit => 'aabbcc'` from your fork or from the the original repository.

Comment: Also `, :branch => 'branch-name-here'` on a given fork.

Comment: For future viewers, here's the whole line will be: `pod 'RestKit', :git => 'https://github.com/#you#/RestKit.git, :branch => 'branch-name-here'`

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question has an accepted answer, I wanted to add an alternative approach. At some time (I believe after this question was asked) the ability to have local references in Podfiles (and not just Podspecs) was added to Cocoapods.

Rather than creating custom creating public forks in Github and custom Podspecs, I find it easier to:

1. Clone the Github library locally.
2. Create a new local branch where I make the changes that I need in that library that are specific to my project.
3. Modify my Podfile to point to that local directory and local branch:

   ```
   pod 'FXForms', :path => '~/Documents/Projects/RestKit', :branch => 'mybranch'
   ```

This makes it easy for me to incorporate any new versions of the library (by just pulling them from origin and then merging them into my local branch).

Comment: This solution only works if you build from your own machine. If you're in a team or have a build server this won't work.