# Will `pod update` overwrite my code changes when a new version of the pod is available?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've added MKStoreKit version 4.99 to my project using cocoapods. My Podfile consists of:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'MKStoreKit', '~> 4.99'
```

MKStoreKit has a configuration file called MKStoreKitConfigs.h that needs to be modified on a per-project basis, and I've modified the file appropriately. What will happen when MKStoreKit releases a new version, say 5.0, and I execute `pod update`? Will my changes be overwritten? Could you describe why yes or why no?

Comment: That's a good question. Its bad design that you have to modify the source code to use the library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, pod update will overwrite your changes. What you could do is fork the project on Github make the changes in your fork and point Cocoapods to the fork. See [Use a fork of Restkit on github via cocoaPod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393470/use-a-fork-of-restkit-on-github-via-cocoapod) on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on overwriting. Forking on Github in this case won't be of much help as my changes contain secret keys which I don't want public and I don't want to burn a private repository on it. The idea and the dependency declaration options were helpful though.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it's a known problem and also as one said: "this is kind of bad practice to configure 3rd party lib in header file".

So at first you can take a look at [this commit](https://github.com/troya2/MKStoreKit/commit/0f862d5183690f579f2ce333b432c0334b31380a). IMO this is a better way to configure it.

Also you can add your fork as a Pod using:

```
pod 'MKStoreKit.MyFork', :path => 'MKStoreKit.MyFork.podspec'
```

EDIT:
Thanks to **rounak** for noticing, `:local` is now `:path`. From [cocoapods](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) docs:

> Using this option (`:path`) CocoaPods will assume the given folder to be the
>   root of the Pod and will link the files directly from there in the
>   Pods project. This means that your edits will persist between
>   CocoaPods installations. The referenced folder can be a checkout of
>   your favourite SCM or even a git submodule of the current repo.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that MKStoreKit version. There are other hardcoded values, mainly related to PHP files (what if I don't want to use PHP???) that aren't addressed in troya2's fork.

Comment: For anyone looking at this now, use :path instead of :local

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I have a fairly simple workaround to keeping changes you make on Pods.

As mentioned, `pod update` will overwrite any changes you made. However, if you're using git what I like to do is commit all my changes except for my pod changes.

Once the only changes I have on my branch are the Pods changes, I stash the pod changes by running `git stash save "Custom Cocoapod changes, apply after every pod update"`. You can give it any message you'd like by changing the text between the "".

This command has the side effect of reseting your working directory to the previous HEAD, so if you want to reapply those stashes you can just run `git stash apply` to get those changes back in, and then you can commit them to save them.

Don't use `git stash pop` as this will delete the stash after applying it.

Now, at some undetermined time in the future, when you update your pods and its time to apply the stash again, what you're going to want to do is run `git stash list`. this will return a list of all the stashes you've made with the most recent being zero indexed. You'll probably see something like this:

```
stash@{0}: On featureFooBar: foo bar
stash@{1}: On Master: Custom Cocoapod changes, apply after every pod update
...
```

If the custom cocoa pods changes stash is in stash@{0} then perfect, you can just run a `git stash apply` again and you'll get those changes on your working directory. Otherwise once you find which stash number your pods changes are you can apply that stash by running `git stash apply stash@{1}`

Applying stashes is easiest when you have a clean working directory on the same branch but thats not required. [This page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) gives a good description of git stash and how to use it otherwise.