# AFNetworking POST AFHTTPRequestOperation Queue issue

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

I'm requesting data from the server but I have an issue that it is calling the cookie first than the data unlike it should be data first than cookie. So please how can I fix this issue?

I've seen this issue via Charles application.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:string
   parameters:@{@"data": @"<p_LM act=\"info\"/>", @"cookie": [temp objectForKey:@"cookie"]}
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

          NSDictionary *dic  = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

          NSString *parity = [dic objectForKey:@"Response"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parameters` is `NSDictionary`. When AF serialize the request it uses **alphabetical** sort descriptor for `NSDictionary`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
```

So, you have two choices:

- rename "data" to e.g. "aaa" then it will be above the "cookie"
- change the sortDescriptor in `AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue` method of the AF pod and take care of it when you do `pod update`.

*edited to specify the second way*

if you want to change the AFNetworking code pod to make it work for you then do:

1. search for AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue method in AFNetworking 
   pod
2. change e.g.

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
   ```

   to

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
   ```

   (just change alphabetical sorting from bottom to top)
3. and then if you will update your AFNetworking pod next time after a
   year or earlier then just add this change again because your change will be overridden by the new pod update ...

Comment: Yeah when I change the data to aata it become the first. How can I take the care of the pod update?

Comment: pod update will overwrite your local changes. so you have to add your code changes everytime when you will update the AF pod. it is not so often.. check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613464/will-pod-update-overwrite-my-code-changes-when-a-new-version-of-the-pod-is-ava

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't understand the solution. Could you please explain it more please?