# Xcode 8: 'objc_unretainedPointer' is unavailable use a __bridge cast instead

Tags: ios, xcode8

Just updated my project to Xcode 8 and I find this errors in multiple external frameworks my app includes. Is there a workaround, maybe touching settings, to avoid this compilation errors?

This is an error example: (That I'm not able to modify because it's an imported framework)

```
const void * ivarPtr = objc_unretainedPointer(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar);
[decoder decodeValueOfObjCType:[ivarInfo[@"encoding"] UTF8String] at:(void *)ivarPtr];
```

Comment: Show the lines causing the errors and the complete error messages.

Comment: What is `ivar`?  Can you provide some more context please?

Comment: ivar is Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(ivarInfo[@"class"], [ivarName UTF8String]); but I believe this is not relevant since there is little I can modify in there due we are talking about code that it's inside of an external framework from an external party.

Answer (score 17):

For Xcode 8, it should be:

```
const void * ivarPtr = (__bridge void *)(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, since this is happening in an external framework I have not the ability to modify.

Comment: @user2461338 So you are seeking a solution that requires no code changes?

Comment: I believe that's the only way. If not, I'll be delighted to hear.

Comment: @user2461338 You got this compiling error while compiling the code. So you have the code, not some binary stuff, why can't modify it?

Comment: It's a pod, so every time I'd do update I'll need to remake the changes. I believe...

Comment: @user2461338 So the question changes to "how to use the fork of a cocoa pod repo". You can take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393470/use-a-fork-of-restkit-on-github-via-cocoapod . Or just send pull requests to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can Simply Replace  `objc_unretainedPointer(self)` to `(__bridge void *)`(self)